# Java Spring - manage threads for sync requests

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-mvc

I have Java web application with REST calls using SPRING.

I want to control the number of threads the application is opening for the requests.

So I added Thread config:

```
package myPackage;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;

@Configuration
public class ThreadConfig {
    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(1);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(1);
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}
```

I'm using Sync service not Async, I tested it and it doesn't limit the threads handling the requests, it handles them all at the same time.

What I was expecting is when I send 2 requests at a time - either the 2nd request will be thrown or it will wait until the 1st request will finish.

I'm not implementing Thread in my application at all.
This is the relevant code from my controller:

```
    @RestController
    public class Module1Controller {
        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "/module1")
InterruptedException {
        public Module1 Module1() throws InterruptedException {
            Date startDate = new Date();
            System.out.println("Thread #: " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " Request received at: " + startDate);
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            Date endDate = new Date();
            long diff = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
            long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(diff);
            System.out.println("Thread #: " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " thread released at: " + endDate + ", total seconds: " + seconds);
            return new Module1(new Clock());
        }
```

This is the console result:

```
Thread #: 34 Request received at: Sun Dec 17 10:16:20 IST 2017
Thread #: 35 Request received at: Sun Dec 17 10:16:21 IST 2017
Thread #: 34 thread released at: Sun Dec 17 10:16:30 IST 2017, total seconds: 10
Thread #: 35 thread released at: Sun Dec 17 10:16:31 IST 2017, total seconds: 10
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I don't think that defining a ThreadPoolExecutor as a bean means that it will be used by your RestController.

Comment: The threads for handling requests are handled by your servlet container. If you want to change that you need to change the configuration of your servlet container. Adding a `TaskExecutor` will not help. Also you don't really want a single thread to handle your requests (well at least not if you want a performant web application that is, if you don't care for that go ahead).

Comment: OK, The single thread configuration was only for testing purpose. Can you elaborate a bit more about the configuration of the servlet container as I didn't define any, it may be part of spring.

Comment: It's not part of Spring. It's part of the servlet container. If you deploy a servlet (even if it is the spring dispatcher servlet) on Tomcat, then Tomcat is the one deciding how to serve requests. If you deploy it on Jetty, then Jetty decides it. So you need to configure your servlet container.

Comment: OK, because the tomcat is embedded in IntelliJ I assume I need to override the tomcat configuration, if so how can I do it, as the properties I found was read only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the creation of a TaskExecutor in a configuration bean has no effect on your RestController.

The easiest way to make your RestController process only 1 request at a time is to make the handling method synchronized, e.g. like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "/module1")
public synchronized Module1 getModule1() throws InterruptedException {
```

If you want a certain maximum number of requests to be processed simultaneously you can use a FixedThreadPool, e.g. like this:

```
// allow only 2 requests at a time, more requests are automatically placed in a queue
private final ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "/module1")
public Module1 getModule1() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    Future<Module1> result = es.submit(new Callable<Module1>() {
        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            try {
                //.... do your work here....
                return Module1()
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    });
    return result.get();
}
```

I'm not sure why you would want to do this. Limiting the number of requests will result in bad performance and users are not going to like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can not control the threads of request in application instead in container. Maybe you want to run some tasks in limited threads in application. You can do like this:

```
@RestController
public class ThreadController {
@Autowired
private TaskExecutor taskExecutor;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "/thread")
public void Module1() {


    taskExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Date startDate = new Date();
            System.out.println("Thread #: " + Thread.currentThread().getId() +
                    " Request received at: " + startDate);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Date endDate = new Date();
            long diff = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
            long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(diff);
            System.out.println("Thread #: " + Thread.currentThread().getId() +
                    " thread released at: " + endDate + ", total seconds: " + seconds);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

The result:

```
Thread #: 55 Request received at: Sun Dec 17 22:40:57 CST 2017
Thread #: 55 thread released at: Sun Dec 17 22:41:07 CST 2017, total seconds: 10
Thread #: 55 Request received at: Sun Dec 17 22:41:16 CST 2017
Thread #: 55 thread released at: Sun Dec 17 22:41:26 CST 2017, total seconds: 10
Thread #: 55 Request received at: Sun Dec 17 22:41:32 CST 2017
Thread #: 55 thread released at: Sun Dec 17 22:41:42 CST 2017, total seconds: 10
```